# @@ROWCOUNT is incorrect on a DELETE (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've never run into this before.  I'm trying to verify that a query is accurate, so I'm doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable mt
   JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.ID = mt.OtherTableID
   JOIN @tablevar tv ON tv.ID = mt.TableVarID;

DELETE mt FROM MyTable mt
   JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.ID = mt.OtherTableID
   JOIN @tablevar tv ON tv.ID = mt.TableVarID;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT * FROM MyTable mt
   JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.ID = mt.OtherTableID
   JOIN @tablevar tv ON tv.ID = mt.TableVarID;
```

The numbers I'm getting, though, are weirdly off.  I'm getting the following results:

> Table with 5208 rows
>
> Success - 51 rows affected
>
> 51
>
> Empty table

The part I don't get is this: the select condition and the delete condition are, so far as I can tell, identical.  So why does the `SELECT` return 5k rows, the `DELETE` removes 51 rows, the `@@ROWCOUNT` claims only 51 rows were affected, but the final `SELECT` shows that the correct number of rows (5k) were removed?

I am aware that `@@ROWCOUNT` is pretty fragile -- anything will overwrite it, just about.  So I looked for triggers in the table in question and found none.

Has anyone run across this?

Comment: In the `SELECT` the original rows from `MyTable` can occur multiple times if more than one row from the joined table match. Yet in the `DELETE` they can only be deleted once. Investigate in this direction.

Comment: Clearly `MyTable` only has 51 rows, however in your initial `SELECT` you have a many to one relationship. Everything is working as intended here; I don't see the problem. If you want to know how many rows are in a specific tables, don't `JOIN` to another table.

Comment: *"the DELETE removes 5k rows"* it doesn't. Your post clearly shows that too when you state `Success - 51 rows affected`. The rows in the other tables are unaffected in your delete; you are only deleting rows in the table aliased `mt` (`MyTable`)

Comment: @stickybit Yeah, I see what you mean.  I didn't think about the one-to-many-ness of this.  I'm looking at the query again, and I can already see that the first join isn't even necessary.  That might be the problem here.

Comment: @Larnu Good catch as well -- I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deleting rows from `MyTable`.  So, the `delete` is saying that 51 rows are being deleted from this table.

Your `select` has two joins that are clearly multiplying the number of rows.

If you want to see what is being deleted, then use `exists`:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OtherTable ot JOIN
                   @tablevar tv
                   ON tv.ID = mt.TableVarID
              WHERE ot.ID = mt.OtherTableID
             );
```

You can use the same logic in the `DELETE`.

Also, to see the rows actually being deleted, you might consider an `OUTPUT` clause.  This allows you to see the rows, not just the count.